# wp_count_posts on all post types?

Tags: plugin-development

I have 5 different custom post types, Is there any way to count all the publish posts regardless of post_type through any inbuilt functions

Like

```
wp_count_posts(array('post','books','video'))
```

any ideas

Answer (score 5):

To get the custom post types you would call the `get_post_types` function.The built-in public post types are post, page, and attachment. By setting '_builtin' to false, we will exclude them and show only the custom public post types. Below is the code.

```
 <?php
$args = array(
'public'   => true,
'_builtin' => false
);
$output = 'names'; // names or objects, note names is the default
$operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
$post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator ); 
foreach ( $post_types  as $post_type ) {
   $count_posts = wp_count_posts($post_type);
   $published_posts = $published_posts+$count_posts->publish;
}
echo $published_posts;
?>
```

Comment: I am speaking about all post types that are registered, Your code just gives count of published posts in default post type "Post"

Comment: @JaganK I have edited my answer.Hope it will helpful.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: published_posts

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_total_posts(){
    $total_posts += (int) wp_count_posts('post')->publish;
    $total_posts += (int) wp_count_posts('page')->publish;
    $total_posts += (int) wp_count_posts('custom')->publish;
    $total_posts += (int) wp_count_posts('other_type')->publish;
    return $total_posts;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code as well as post it.

Comment: `wp_count_posts` runs a query every time it is called, making that fairly heavy code, and new types would have to be added manually making it high maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

I use to add all post

```
$total_codes = wp_count_posts(codes);
$total_themes = wp_count_posts('themes');


$codes_count = $total_codes->publish;
$themes_count = $total_themes->publish;
$sum_total = $codes_count + $themes_count;

print ($direct_text . $sum_total);
```

Comment: Shadab is calling the `publish` property to get the number of post with status "publish"

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct.

Answer (score -1):

Just try this and reply whether it worked out this will give all pusblish posts ..

```
<?php 
// Get all published pages
$published_pages = wp_count_posts()->publish;
echo 'Total published posts: ' . $published;
?>
```

Comment: I am speaking about all post types that are registered, Your code just gives count of published posts in default post type "Post"

Comment: hi then may this post is wat ur looking for i believe if not reply back...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067698/wordpress-count-user-posts-of-different-custom-post-types

Comment: That fulfills my needs, but not answers my question. So i guess there's no default function to count all post types.